# How to out put a nest block in cms?

Tags: magento2, blocks, cms

like this

```
<block class="Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\PostList\Item" name="blog.posts.list.item" template="post/list/item.phtml">
      <block class="Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\Info" name="blog.post.info" template="post/info.phtml" />
         <action method="setPostInfoBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">blog.post.info</argument>
         </action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a layout file in this path:

```
Magefan/Blog/view/base/layout/magefan_blog_cms_postlist.xml
```

And like any other layout define all your blocks and nested blocks (as you have posted in your question).

> Note: your template files should be in view/base

And then in CMS page or block use it like:

```
{{layout handle="magefan_blog_cms_postlist"}}
```

There is no way to define nested blocks in CMS directly. You need to use your custom layout and layout handle.

Comment: Thanks ! It works for me. Another problem is whether it is feasible to put the layout file into the custom theme folder

Comment: Yes you can, actually base is used for both frontend and backend. You can put into theme as well like: Magefan_Blog/layout and similar for template as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
{{block class="Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\PostList\Item" template="Magefan_Blog::post/list/item.phtml"}}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I try and it doesn't work

Comment: You can put it on cms page then save and clear cache to see result

Comment: Any new result ?